# Convert dateline number to time string in QML

Tags: javascript, qml

I have dateline numbers, how can i convert these numbers to time strings in qml? This is what i have tried but got errors, committedDate is int number which holds number of milliseconds from epoch.

```
Text {
    id: timeText
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: Date(committedDate).toTimeString()
    color: "white"
}
```

the error is

> qrc:/Conversation.qml:1940: TypeError: Property 'toTimeString' of
>   object Sun Dec 25 11:08:45 2016 GMT+0330 is not a function

Answer (score 1):

There are date formatting options in the `Qt` object/namespace:

```
Qt.formatDate()
Qt.formatDateTime()
Qt.formatTime()
```

E.g.

```
text: Qt.formatDateTime(Date(milliseconds), Qt.ISODate)
```